# bootstrap carousel does not work correctly using partial file

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am new to bootstrap and AngularJs. I am using bootstrap and Angular Js for my current application. When I use the bootstrap carousel directly inside the index page, the carousel's slide link are working absolutely perfect. But When I load the carousel markup through the partial files using ng-view, the slide links does not work correctly. It only works one time and then just don't work the next time. Where I am going wrong. I am pasting the code below:

```
<div class="corousal-container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul id="tabs" class="ops-tabs">
      <li class="col-md-4 ops-list active">
        <a href="#" class="ops-block">
          <span class="header">Charts</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-md-4 ops-list">
        <a href="#" class="ops-block">
          <span class="header">Graphs</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-md-4 ops-list">
        <a href="#" class="ops-block">
          <span class="header">Reports</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide" id="execView">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#execView" class="active"></li>
      <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#execView" class=""></li>
      <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#execView" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="container" id="pie-chart1">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="container" id="pie-chart2">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="container" id="pie-chart3">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a data-slide="prev" href="#execView" class="left carousel-control"><span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span></a>
    <a data-slide="next" href="#execView" class="right carousel-control"><span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am seeing that when I click the link, its calling the controller and then again loading the ng-view which is why the slider does not work correctly. Any suggestion to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ng-view then you need to create your bootstrap `carousel` after the html is loaded. You can do this in the `onload` method.

```
<div ng-view onload="viewLoaded()"></div>


$scope.viewLoaded=function(){
 $('.carousel ').carousel()
}
```

Comment: What goes inside the `viewLoaded` function? There is no javascript code. I am just using the bootstrap css code. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: It is executed after your HTML is loaded. Otherwise you are trying to create a carousel before your partial loaded which is not working.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not understand what is getting executed after the HTML is loaded. The sliders are working because of CSS i believe. Can you please let me know the code that needs to go inside the `viewLoaded` function?

Comment: I did not understand this: `$('.carousel ').carousel()`. Where is `carousel()` function defined?

Comment: That is in Bootstrap.js

Answer (score 2):

Use angular Bootstrap directives for this.

> http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/